# count no of rows in table from web application using python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

How to count no of rows in table from web application using selenium python webdriver... I tried this one but didn't work:

```
rowcount = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class='alert-list table']/tbody/tr")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    rowCount=self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class='alert-list table']/tbody/tr").size();
```